# Is it possible to protect a non-pinned managed array?

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection, unmanaged, unsafe

I need to protect the managed array from writing. I can do this by calling VirtualProtect. But GC can execute compact managed memory and move a not fixed array to another location. Will the access rights be transferred, or does the GC know nothing about them? Is there a way to protect a not fixed managed array from writing in this case?

**Update 1:**
[image]

**Update 2:**
`GC.Alloc` does not help. Any attempt to put the ReadOnly attribute on the memory page causes the GC to throw an exception.

Comment: In short words, **no** - there is currently no API available in GC to write-protect any memory managed by it. .NET runtime has a concept of read-only segments but they are not publicly available. CLR hosting also won't help here - you have there control over Virtual API calls, but for all memory.
In such low-level requirement, I would just go off-the-heap with such write protected array.

Comment: just a footnote on what @KonradKokosa says there; if you *did* go with unmanaged memory, keep in mind that you can use `Memory<T>` and `Span<T>` backed by a pointer, so that your C# can still talk to it without needing `unsafe` and pointers everywhere (or perhaps `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` / `ReadOnlySpan<T>` if you've marked it as read-only)

Comment: @MarcGravell Unfortunately, Span has not yet been brought to the .NET Framework.
Memory <T> will help me solve the problem if I use unmanaged memory. But I need to call VirtualProtect to protect the memory area after it is returned to the pool.

Comment: @LunarWhisper https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/ - goes all the way to .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Standard 1.1

Answer (score 1):

It's working.

The problem is VirtualProtect is blocking whole pages of memory. Managed arrays are not aligned to the page border. Thus, VirtualProtect touches memory that does not belong to an array.